# Allowing unidirectional access from parent to iframe of same origin

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, parent

Is there any way by which I can make the parent document access the iFrame DOM but avoid the iFrame from accessing parent DOM? That is, I want only unidirectional access from my parent to the iframe DOM. My use-case is that I am trying to install Facebook conversion pixel on a webpage that I own. I dont want the facebook javascript (fbds.js) to access my DOM, so I am creating a new webpage on my domain, loading the facebook javascript into the newly created page, and loading the new page in an iFrame on my original webpage . Now I need to restrict that iframe from accessing parent DOM (for security) but allow my parent to trigger javascript functions in the iFrame window (to track events).